# NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: css selector but im using find_element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I used selenium IDE to trace my UI activity. I got this following code from IDE and i inspected in UI also,but while using find_element by id i'm getting css selector error.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "button-1034-btnIconEl").click()
```

error is

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="button-1034-btnIconEl"]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

[image]

Please help me to debug this..

Comment: seems like the error getting from different code segment, `button-1034-btnEl` in the error but using your 'button-1034-btnIconEl' in the code. could you share full code segment to get better idea

Comment: Sorry i have tried all the span button id under <a>..now i edited my code

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the *button* with text as **Add Order** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[id^='button-'] > span.x-btn-wrap > span.x-btn-button > span.x-btn-inner.x-btn-inner-center"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@id, 'button-')]/span[@class='x-btn-wrap']/span[@class='x-btn-button']/span[@class='x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center' and contains(., 'Add')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on **`NoSuchElementException: no such element`** in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Answer (score 0):

The id seems to be dynamic one so you cannot use static id in the selector. You need to use a dynamic xpath for this.
You can use the below xpath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@id,'btnIconEl')]").click()
```

OR

You can find the element using its text as well in the xpath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Add Order')]").click()
```

Comment: Hi Sameer , i tried first one getting, "ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable " Error. and if i use second, same error "no such element"

Comment: yes i can.i used selenium IDE chrome extension, through that only i got this code.

Comment: @AnuPriya i have edited the second xpath, please try that one and let me know the result

Comment: Finally what i found was inside div there is one iframe so in that iframe this button is presented. so now how to select the frame?

Comment: Yes so you need to first switch to the iframe and then click on the button. To switch on the iframe you should use: `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('iframe'))` and then you need to click on the button using the xpath mentioned in my answer

Comment: @AnuPriya if the iframe id is not present then please send me the html of the iframe, i will help you to detect the iframe using any other locator

Comment: Thanku @Sameer. for the confidentiality of my company i can't share but i posted the snippet please comment in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59302960/how-to-click-button-which-is-inside-iframe-using-python-selenium

Comment: @AnuPriya I am sure that you discovered the _iframe_ after going through my answer ;) you are denying my doughnut :)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be your case, but I made a silly mistake that lead me to this error.
I forgot to get the actual web page using the line:

```
driver.get(my_link)
```

and thus, I got the same error