# how to click button which is inside iframe using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

He is my sample snippet. i want to click the button-1034-btnIconEl using python selenium.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="x-container x-border-item x-box-item x-container-default x-layout-fit" id="iframes" >
<iframe ></iframe>
<iframe class="x-component x-fit-item x-component-default" frameborder="0"  id="rpIFrame-1239">
 <html>
 <body>
 <div> .....many divs 
  <div>
   <a><span><span id="button-1034-btnIconEl"></span></span></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

i tried this

```
 driver.switch_to.frame(1)
 driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@id,'button-1034-btnIconEl')]").click()
```

but getting

> "NoSuchElementException: no such element:"

Please help me to traverse this.

Comment: try out this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use the frame `id` instead of index

```
driver.switch_to.frame('rpIFrame-1239')
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch on the iframe you can use:

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))`

Comment: still same "NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="rpIFrame-1239"]"}" .  this frame is inside div.so does i have to switch div ? @Sameer

Comment: i gave time.sleep(20) to load the page.. after that also not finding the element

Comment: I have edited the locator for the iframe. Please use the new one

Comment: @AnuPriya i have changed the path now, please check now

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the button with *id* as **button-1034-btnIconEl** as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.x-component.x-fit-item.x-component-default[id^='rpIFrame-']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a > span > span[id^='button'][id$='btnIconEl']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='x-component x-fit-item x-component-default' and starts-with(@id, 'rpIFrame-')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a/span/span[starts-with(@id, 'button') and contains(@id, 'btnIconEl')]"))).click()
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: @AnuPriya The xml and the locators are tested and pretty much in sync. Possibly you made a mistake while handcrafting the HTML. Recheck and retest and let me know the status.